# SQL Server Express 2016 Installation failing

Tags: sql-server, installation

I've recently tried to install the latest version of SQL Server Express 2016, but right at the end of the installation I get the following error:
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

No extra information seems to be available and the installation of following components show up as failed:

Database Engine Services
Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for Search
R Services
SQL Server Replication

I've tried to uninstall everything and install again several times but I always get the same error. I am using Windows 8.1 Enterprise.

Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have Client Tools installed? If so what is the version? You may need to update the installed version.

Comment: No, I do not have Client Tools Installed. Thanks